# Can't remove an item by its index - 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, enumerate

I have a nested list with elements. I want the user to remove one list when he/she types an index of the list: So let's say the user types: "0" so `['elem', 'elem1', 'elem2']` will be deleted.

```
0 ['elem', 'elem1', 'elem2']
1 ['elem3', 'elem4', 'elem5']
2 ['elem6', 'elem7', 'elem8']
3 ['elem9', 'elem', 'elem10']
```

My code works without the function, but when I try to create a function, I receive an error that I don't understand.

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

```
database = [['elem', 'elem1', 'elem2'],
                  ['elem3', 'elem4', 'elem5'],
                  ['elem6', 'elem7', 'elem8'], 
                  ['elem9', 'elem', 'elem10']]


def remove_from_database(index):
  if index in database:
    database.pop(index)
    return index
  else:
    print("not here")

for index, elem in enumerate(database):
  print(index, elem)

user = remove_from_database(int(input("type in the index to remove: ")))
result = database.pop(user)
print(f"removed: {result}")
```

Could someone please tell me what this error means? Does it mean that the index is not actually an int? How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure the check is `if index in database`? I'd suggest using a comparison with `len(database)`

Comment: `remove_from_database` may return `None`, which you then use in `pop` as   an `index` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with your "def remove_from_database(index)".
You check for the "0" in the database - Of course it will not be there.

If you rewrite your method like this, it will work:

```
def remove_from_database(index):
    try:
        database.pop(index)
    except:
        print("Not in here")
```

Answer (score 1):

You had few mistakes. You've tried to pop elements again from database outside method, your if compare won't work right.

```
database = [['elem', 'elem1', 'elem2'],
                  ['elem3', 'elem4', 'elem5'],
                  ['elem6', 'elem7', 'elem8'],
                  ['elem9', 'elem', 'elem10']]


def remove_from_database(index):
  if index < len(database):
    return database.pop(index)
  else:
    print("not here")
  return None

for index, elem in enumerate(database):
  print(index, elem)

user = int(input("type in the index to remove: "))
result = remove_from_database(user)
print(f"removed: {result}") 
#in older Python ver  
#print("removed: {0}".format(result))
```

Instead of `if else`, you can also use @Markus sugestion and it should work even better.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, now it works. I didn't know 'len' would work here.

Comment: Re print statement: print(f"removed: {result}") also works, I think this is available in the newest Python version

Comment: You are right, It was added in Python 3.6, i didn't knwo about it, and i have installed 3.5 on this computer so i was getting an error, my bad.

Comment: No problem at all! :)